# MVC Html.DropDownList selected value being overriden by QueryString value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using a dropdownlist in my view like so:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ClientId", Model.AvailableClients, "-- None --")
```

Model.AvailableClients is an IEnumerable one of the item's Selected property is set to true.  If in the query string for the page request includes "ClientId=" (as in its not set) MVC ignores my selected item.  I assume this is because MVC is trying to be helpful and set the selected item automatically using the querystring, but I dont want this.

How can I prevent the querystring value from overriding my item's selected value?

Answer (score 0):

If the name you give your DropDownList is already the name of an element in your model then DropDownList will automatically override the selected value with the model value. If letting ClientId determine the selected value isn't an option then the only solution I know is to rename the DropDownList with a name not included in the model.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ClientId)
@Html.DropDownList("ClientIdNewName", Model.AvailableClients, "-- None --", new { onchange = "ClientId.value = this.value"})
```

This will keep the value in ClientId without making it the default selection value.

Comment: I need to be able to override it so that if the user requests a ClientId that either doesnt exist or they dont have access to the code can pick an appropriate alternative

Comment: @Mr Bell Couldn't you set the ClientId to the appropriate alternative in your controller? Or set the appropriate alternative selecteditem in your Model.AvailableClients and then use a different name for the drop down list?

Comment: If you use a different name for the drop down then the model will not be properly populated on posting back to the controller.  If you separate out the field into another field then your initial object validation wont work

Comment: @Mr Bell Editted answer. Found a way to keep the ClientId field without using it as the default. I tested on my code, it works.